# IIS SMTP Relay emails got stuck in queue

Tags: smtp, gmail

As part of My Lab, I had an IIS SMTP relay server with a Gmail account, configured well, and worked for some time. but from the past 2 days, it's not sending emails got stuck in Q.

in the Windows Event log says The **connection was dropped by the remote host**.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is no longer supported as of May 30th, 2022. See https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en&visit_id=637896899107643254-869975220&p=less-secure-apps&rd=1#zippy=%2Cuse-an-app-password